# In a C# class library how can I detect when the DLL is about to be unloaded?

Tags: c#, dll

I need to write a static List to a text file when a DLL is unloaded. I've tried doing this on AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload but it crashes with the error "DefaultDataCollection failed: 0x8007001f".

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Only debuggers can trace DLL unload notifications.  Programs cannot debug themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 0x8007001f

That's a WIN32 error (the 7 in the middle is `FACILITY_WIN32`): `ERROR_GEN_FAILURE`:

> A device attached to the system is not functioning.

So you need to look at the exception type and stack trace to get more details of what is failing.

> `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload`

but remember the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.domainunload.aspx) has the caveat:

> This event is never raised in the default application domain.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't error when debugging. Only when running so all I can't actualy attach to it to get the stac trace.

Comment: @user940516: Without a debugger, write to some other output, the details of the exception (without it you are just guessing).